# Open a select2 select box in angularjs E2E test

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to E2E test my angularjs application. It has a select2 select box that is populated with items from an API. This select2 select box has a list of filters that will be added to a search.

```
<input id="filter-select2" ui-select2="dataArray" ng-model="selected"/>
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to open the select box in the E2E tests I'm doing. If I load the application I'm able to do `$('#s2id_filter-select2').select2('open');` in the Chrome Javascript Console to open the select2 select box. I'm also able to do `angular.element('#s2id_filter-select2').select2('open');`.

But if I try to do this in the E2E tests themselves the element doesn't seem to have `.select2()`.

I tried both `element('#s2id_filter-select2').select2('open');` and

```
element('#s2id_filter-select2').query(function (e, done) {
    e.select2('open');
    done();
});
```

in the E2E test. I'm able to call `.fadeOut()` in the latter example (`element().query()`), but not `.select2()`.

I tried including select2.js and angularui.js (I'm using the directive from angular-ui) in the E2E test config but that doesn't change anything.

Has anyone had any success in calling some jQuery libraries, such as select2, from an E2E test?

I also thought about just skipping the select2 box, that is, setting the "selected" model directly, since I have a $watch that will update the application on filter select, but I can't seem to find a way to set the model through the test itself.

The e2e config is using the following files:

```
files = [
    ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
    ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
    'tests/students/scenarios/*.scenario.js',
    'dev/students/js/script.js',
    'dev/students/js/*.js'
];
```

I tried having select2, jQuery and angular-ui included both before and after the tests/ and dev/ files.

**Edit:** I am able to set the selected model with `input('selected').enter('sth');`, but I can't seem to be able to set it as a model. I might have to write a custom DSL for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use a custom DSL to open select2 boxes in angular e2e tests. I take no credit for the following code block, I found it at:
[How to execute jQuery from Angular e2e test scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400720/how-to-execute-jquery-from-angular-e2e-test-scope)

By adding:

```
angular.scenario.dsl('jQueryFunction', function() {
    return function(selector, functionName /*, args */) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        return this.addFutureAction(functionName, function($window, $document, done) {
            var $ = $window.$; // jQuery inside the iframe
            var elem = $(selector);
            if (!elem.length) {
                return done('Selector ' + selector + ' did not match any elements.');
            }
            done(null, elem[functionName].apply(elem, args));
        });
    };
});
```

to the top of your e2e test file, you can then open a select2 box like so:

```
jQueryFunction('#s2id_roleselect', 'select2', 'open');
```

replacing roleselect with your own id. All credit goes to user Jeroen V. for supplying the DSL.

Comment: Sorry for a late answer, I had stopped working on this project shortly before you answered. I just had some dead time now though and decided to try it out and it works perfectly. Thank you very much! It feels good to be able to use something other than ugly workarounds in the code.